# Comparing the last index of a list in order to manipulate variables with that index

Tags: python, indexing, compare

This block of code is taking a list of lists (created from a csv file) and attempting to organize it.  I know it looks really messy, I've been coding for a couple of months in school.

Anyway, the code compares the first 7 characters of the first index of the `[c]` index (as I have to go through all 2500+ lists in this list).  If they are the same, I do some math with those variables.

All of it works except the final grouping of data. I get "index out of range" or something along those lines because of the `[c+1]` when `while c <len(dataList)`, which is why I added the +1 to the while statement.

The bottom if-else statement has no effect on my code I don't think, but that was my attempt at solving this problem. Please explain how I could clean up this code. Thanks!

```
while c+1 < len(dataList):
    if dataList[c][0][0:7] == dataList[c+1][0][0:7]:
        totalVolume += float(dataList[c][5])
        volClose += (float(dataList[c][5]) * float(dataList[c][4]))
        c +=1
    else:
        volClose += (float(dataList[c][5]) * float(dataList[c][4]))
        totalVolume += float(dataList[c][5])
        avgPrice = volClose/totalVolume
        averageList.append((dataList[c][0][0:7], avgPrice))
        c +=1

        count += 1
        volClose = 0
        totalVolume = 0
        avgPrice = 0            

if c == len(dataList):
    if dataList[c][0][0:7] == dataList[c+1][0][0:7]:
        totalVolume += float(dataList[c][5])
        volClose += (float(dataList[c][5]) * float(dataList[c][4]))
        c +=1
    else:
        volClose += (float(dataList[c][5]) * float(dataList[c][4]))
        totalVolume += float(dataList[c][5])
        avgPrice = volClose/totalVolume
        averageList.append((dataList[c][0][0:7], avgPrice))
        c +=1         


return averageList
```

Comment: If you're comparing consecutive elements in a list of length n, you usually want to either make n-1 comparisons, or make n comparisons where you end by comparing the last element to the very first (i.e. you go full circle).  Is either of those your intention here?

Comment: I could compare it to the first element,  but I'm not sure how to loop it around to get to the first element then.  The first and last element are not equal to each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python begins counting at 0, so you cannot go to an index that is equal to the length of the list.  For example, a list like `['a', 'b', 'c']` has a length of 3, with indices 0, 1, and 2.  That is why you get an error.

Comment: Is there any way around this problem? Without changing the list at all?

Comment: It's not a problem, just a convention.  So to iterate through the list I gave, you would just start with i = 0, and end when i == 2.  In other words, while i is less than the length of the list, which is 3.

Comment: please try to use len(lst) - 1